# Django cropper - getting additional resized images from cropped image

Tags: django, django-models

I have problem with getting additional resized images from croped image. I am using django-cropper 0.1.
Originally model for Cropped Image have part of code like this:

```
class Cropped(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s-%sx%s' % (self.original, self.w, self.h)

    def upload_image(self, filename):
        return '%s/crop-%s' % (settings.ROOT, filename)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        source = self.original.image.path
        target = self.upload_image(os.path.basename(source))

        Image.open(source).crop([
            self.x,             # Left
            self.y,             # Top
            self.x + self.w,    # Right
            self.y + self.h     # Bottom
        ]).save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + os.sep + target)


        self.image = target        
        super(Cropped, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But i want to have additional resized images from cropped image so I change code a little and now it looks like that:

```
class Cropped(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s-%sx%s' % (self.original, self.w, self.h)

    def _get_average_path(self):
        return _add_average(self.path)
    average_path = property(_get_average_path)

    def _get_average_url(self):
        return _add_average(self.url)
    average_url = property(_get_average_url)

    def _get_large_path(self):
        return _add_large(self.path)
    large_path = property(_get_large_path)

    def _get_large_url(self):
        return _add_large(self.url)
    large_url = property(_get_large_url)

    def upload_image(self, filename):
        return '%s/crop-%s' % (settings.ROOT, filename)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        source = self.original.image.path
        target = self.upload_image(os.path.basename(source))

        img = Image.open(source).crop([
            self.x,             # Left
            self.y,             # Top
            self.x + self.w,    # Right
            self.y + self.h     # Bottom
        ]).save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + os.sep + target)

        self.image = target        
        super(Cropped, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        img = img.resize((180, 180), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(self.large_path, 'JPEG')

        img = img.resize((104, 104), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save(self.average_path, 'JPEG')
```

But it still doing the basic job. Can someone help me and give any suggestion of what should I fix in this code?

Comment: Well, I don't find any place in your code where additional variants are generated. You just implemented some additional methods, but they are never called. BTW, would using a templated-based approach like django-cuddlybuddly an alternative way? For me, it works better.

Comment: django-cuddlybuddly? I take look at it but it seems doesn't has feature of cropping image on displayed page. OF maybe I am wrong. So could You help me by telling what should I do to call method of saving additional images?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question because i found solution and maybe it someone. Maybe it is now the best solution, but it works. First it is needed to add additional field for additional, resized image:

```
average = models.ImageField(
    blank=True, null=True,
    verbose_name = _('Image'),
    upload_to    = upload_image,
    editable     = False,
)
```

Then it is needed to chnge save() method to something like this:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        source = self.original.image.path
        target = self.upload_image(os.path.basename(source))

        Image.open(source).crop([
            self.x,             # Left
            self.y,             # Top
            self.x + self.w,    # Right
            self.y + self.h     # Bottom
        ]).save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + os.sep + target)
        self.image = target

        splited_target = target.split("/")
        avepath = "/average-".join(splited_target) 
        self.average = avepath

        Image.open(self.image).resize((104, 104), Image.ANTIALIAS).save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + avepath, 'JPEG')
        super(Cropped, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And that is all.